# How to replace one line with two lines using sed in csh on BSD?

Tags: sed, freebsd, csh

I have a very simple text file here with the following contents

```
line1
line2
line3
line4
```

I want to modify the contents via sed(or some other app) so it becomes

```
line1
line2
#this line was added by sed
line3
line4
```

So I tried `sed -e "s/line2/line2\\n#this line was added by sed/" my-text-file-here.txt`, but the output is:

```
line1
line2\n#this line was added by sed
line3
line4
```

Any ideas on how to do it correctly? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is assuming the `csh` shell:

To simply append a line after another:

```
% sed '/line2/a\\
# new line here\
' file
line1
line2
# new line here
line3
line4
```

To insert a line before another:

```
% sed '/line3/i\\
# new line here\
' file
line1
line2
# new line here
line3
line4
```

To substitute a line with two new lines using the `s` command:

```
% sed 's/line2/&\\
# new line here/' file
line1
line2
# new line here
line3
line4
```

Tested on OpenBSD 6.1 running `sed` and `csh` from the base system.

Answer (score 4):

With GNU sed, your code works just fine:

```
$ sed -e 's/line2/line2\n#this line was added by sed/' file
line1
line2
#this line was added by sed
line3
line4
```

For BSD sed, however, `\n` is not treated as a newline in the replacement text.  If your shell is bash, a good work-around is to use `$'...'` to insert the newline:

```
$ sed -e $'s/line2/line2\\\n#this line was added by sed/' file
line1
line2
#this line was added by sed
line3
line4
```

In addition to bash, zsh and ksh support `$'...'`.

Another option is to insert a real newline:

```
$ sed -e 's/line2/line2\
#this line was added by sed/' file
line1
line2
#this line was added by sed
line3
line4
```

UPDATE: In csh, this last option requires an additional `\`:

```
% sed -e 's/line2/line2\\
#this line was added by sed/' file
line1
line2
#this line was added by sed
line3
line4
```

Comment: The second example doesn't work in `csh`, which is what the OP is using. `csh` doesn't have `$'...'`. I also couldn't get your third example to run in `csh` (`#this lin ...: unescaped newline inside substitute pattern`). `csh` has funky string handling.

Comment: Thank you for that info.  _"The second example doesn't work in csh..."_  The text clearly states that the second example was for `bash`.  `$'...'` is not POSIX but it is supported by bash, ksh, and zsh.  The info that the OP was using csh was added to the question 2 hours __after__ I wrote my answer.

Comment: @Kusalananda Since I wrote my comment, the question was modified again this time removing mention csh.

Comment: I missed the mentioning of Bash there, sorry!  The edit was done by @AFSHIN, not by the owner of the question.

Comment: @Kusalananda I see that you have edited the question to restore the info.  Very good.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you want the **a**ppend command, really.  Using Bash or any shell that supports `$'\n'` (most do):

```
sed $'/line2/a\\\n#this line was added by sed\n' file.txt
```

Or, more readably, using a sed commands file:

```
/line2/a\
#this line was added by sed
```

To show the full method:

```
$ cat file.txt 
line1
line2
line3
line4
$ cat sedfile 
/line2/a\
#this line was added by sed
$ sed -f sedfile file.txt 
line1
line2
#this line was added by sed
line3
line4
$
```

Comment: I noticed something odd while writing this answer; see https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/390845/135943