# Is the use of sed's "a" command to prefix a line portable?

Tags: sed, posix, portability

I noticed the following interesting behavior:

```
$ printf '%s\n' line{1..2} | sed $'1a\\\nPREFIX'
line1
PREFIXline2
$
```

Interestingly, this behavior is only possible for the *last* command in a Sed script, as to put another command afterwards requires a newline.

It also works with the insert command:

```
$ printf '%s\n' line{1..2} | sed $'1i\\\nPREFIX'
PREFIXline1
line2
$
```

**Can this behavior be depended upon?**

I don't see it mentioned one way or another in the [POSIX specs for Sed](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sed.html).  It just says that the `text` may consist of one or more lines.  (If a line doesn't end in a newline character, is it still a line?)

It also works with multiple line insertions:

```
$ printf '%s\n' line{1..2} | sed $'1a\\\n ****/\n1i\\\n/****\\\n * '
/****
* line1
****/
line2
$
```

Comment: Related; my earlier misadventures with BSD Sed: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/312579/135943

Comment: I consider this behaviour to be inconsistent, as the newline following the insertion is not part of the insertion, but closes the `a`/`i` command, so it should not be treated different from the insertion at the end of the script. Whether or not the newline is to be output at all, is ambiguous in the standard, as I see it, so theoretically your `sed` could insert it or not, but should to it independent from whether this is the last command.

Comment: That's clearly a bug. POSIX does say for that script given as argument: _A string to be used as the script of editing commands. The application shall not present a script that violates the restrictions of a text file except that the final character
             need not be a newline_ implying that the newline is implied. `sed -e x` is the same as `sed -f file` where `file` contains `x\n`. Actually, you'll find that `sed  -e script` works OK, only `sed script` has the issue confirming even more clearly that it is a bug.

Answer (score 1):

To prefix a line with a string, use a substitution (`s`) and replace `^`, the start-of-line anchor:

```
$ printf 'line1\nline2\n' | sed '1s/^/PREFIX/'
PREFIXline1
line2
```

Use `a` to append lines after some line, and `i` to insert a line before another line.  The `a` and `i` commands are not meant for modifying lines, just adding lines.

"Can this behavior be depended upon?" No. As  Stéphane Chazelas points out in comments, "That's clearly a bug", and GNU `sed` does not show the described behaviour.

---

Regarding your question "If a line doesn't end in a newline character, is it still a line?", [POSIX defines a "line" as](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2016edition/basedefs/V1_chap03.html#tag_03_206)

> A sequence of zero or more non-`<newline>` characters plus a terminating `<newline>` character.

So the answer to that question is "no, it is not a line".

Answer (score 0):

I just tested with a different Sed and found this is a peculiarity of BSD Sed; GNU Sed gives different results best illustrated with the output of the last command given above:

```
$ printf '%s\n' line{1..2} | sed $'1a\\\n ****/\n1i\\\n/****\\\n * '
/****
 *
line1
 ****/
line2
$
```